# Is there a way to pass SSEKMSKeyId and ServerSideEncryption to scrapy FilesPipeline using AWS S3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scrapy

Is there a way to pass SSEKMSKeyId and ServerSideEncryption to scrapy FilesPipeline using AWS S3 or do I need to write a separate pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

1. Subclass `scrapy.pipelines.files.S3FilesStore`, and extend its `HEADERS` class attribute in your subclass to define the headers you want with the values you want.

   In your case, the corresponding headers are: `X-Amz-Server-Side-Encryption`, `X-Amz-Server-Side-Encryption-Aws-Kms-Key-Id` (you can see the header-to-key mapping in the source code of the class, for additional header names).
2. Subclass `FilesPipeline`, and edit the `STORE_SCHEMES` class attribute in your subclass to point `s3` to your `S3FilesStore` subclass.
3. Update your `ITEM_PIPELINES` setting to use your `FilesPipeline` subclass.